# Converting ## to number regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am holding in a field the validation format that I would need.
I need to convert different ## into a regex validation.

Is there a simple replace that can do this for me.
for example, i need to validate the account number.
sometimes it might need to be ###-###, or I'll get ####### or ##-####.
depending what is in the id="validationrule" field
I'm looking for

```
regex = $('#validationrule').replace("#", "[0/9]");
```

It also has to take into consideration that sometimes there is a dash in there.

Comment: Why do you chain `.replace()` to a jQuery object?

Comment: Is your question how to convert a string to a regular expression? `$('#validationrule')` probably returns a jQuery object, not a string. Is your question how to get the value from an input field in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be about creating regexes from a string variable (which you get from an input field that specifies the validation format).

- `"###-###"` might turn into `/^\d{3}\-\d{3}$/`
- `"#######"` might turn into `/^\d{7}$/`

If your validation format is built from the 2 characters `#` and `-`, this would work:

```js
function createValidationRegEx(format){
  format = format
    .replace(/[^#\-]/g, '') //remove other chars
    .replace(/#/g, '\\d')   //convert # to \d
    .replace(/\-/g, '\\-'); //convert - to \-
  return new RegExp('^' + format + '$', 'g');
}

//create regexes
var format1 = createValidationRegEx('###-###');
var format2 = createValidationRegEx('#######');

//test regexes
console.log(format1.test('123-456')); // true
console.log(format2.test('123-456')); // false

console.log(format1.test('1234567')); // false
console.log(format2.test('1234567')); // true
```

Please note that you need to pay attention to which characters needs to be escaped when creating regexes from strings. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) provides more details about how to solve this more generally, if you want to build more complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace the `.value` of an `<input>` element you can use `.val(function)`, `return` replacement string from `.replace()` inside of `function`, chain `.val()` to assign result to `regex`. Use `RegExp` constructor with `g` flag to replace all matches of the `RegExp` supplied to `.replace()` to match characters against at string.

```js
var regex = $("#validationrule").val(function(_, val) {
              return val.replace("#", "[0/9]");
            }).val();

console.log(regex);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="validationrule" value="#">
```